# Why am I unable to instantiate a class object in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity C# script that spawns a grid of rooms. These rooms are defined by the class "Room" which is stored inside a script of the same name. When I attempt to create a new Room for my grid of rooms, I get the compiler error:

> 'Room' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

The Room class is written as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Drawing;

public class Room {
        private Point coords;
        private string referenceName;
        private GameObject roomGO;
        private Room north, east, south, west;

        private int layer;

        public Room(string theReferenceName, Point theCoords, int theLayer) {
            referenceName = theReferenceName;
            coords = theCoords;
            layer = theLayer;
        }

        // Return the neighbor at the given direction. If no neighbor exists to that
        // direction, return null.
        public Room getNeighbor(string theNeighbor) {
            switch (theNeighbor) {
                case "north" : 
                    if (north is not null) {
                        return north; 
                    }
                    break;
                case "east" : 
                    if (east is not null) {
                        return east; 
                    }
                    break;
                case "south" : 
                    if (south is not null) {
                        return south; 
                    }
                    break;
                case "west" : 
                    if (west is not null) {
                        return west; 
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void setNeighbor(string theDirection, Room theNewNeighbor) {
            switch (theDirection) {
                case "north" : 
                    north = theNewNeighbor;
                    break;
                case "east" : 
                    east = theNewNeighbor;
                    break;
                case "south" :
                    south = theNewNeighbor;
                    break;
                case "west" : 
                    west = theNewNeighbor;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void setRoomGO (GameObject theRoomGO) {
            if (theRoomGO != null) {
                roomGO = theRoomGO;
            }
        }

        public string getReferenceName() {
            return referenceName;
        }

        public void setReferenceName(string theNewReferenceName) {
            referenceName = theNewReferenceName;
        }

        public Point getCoords() {
            return coords;
        }

        public int getLayer() {
            return layer;
        }

        public void setLayer(int theNewLayer) {
            layer = theNewLayer;
        }
    }
```

And the code that creates a new Room looks as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++) {
        dungeon[i, j] = new Room(" ", new Point(i, j), 0);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? This causes a lot more compiler errors saying that Room does not contain a definition for methods and no accessible extension method could be found.

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes Unity made (and continues to) is to generate MonoBehaviour files **without an enclosing namespace** that has led to many picking up the bad habit.  Though Unity provides a few places for you to enter it in the Editor GUI, never does it actually appear in the generated **.CS** file (only the project file where R# detects it).  I suspect neither your **Room.cs** nor your room-spawning MonoBehaviour contain any `namespace { }` declaration and that the latter is actually referring to **another** `Room` type defined in your project.  Add a namespace to all your files.

Comment: @MickyD I added the namespace "Rooms" to the Room script and added "using Rooms" to my spawning script and just got the error, "The type of namespace name 'Rooms' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Please post your updated code.